# слайдер Swiper react typescript не настраивается свойство slidesPerView: 'auto'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swiper

Спасайте!! Уже несколько часов бьюсь над задачей. У меня в react-приложении есть компонент Slider.tsx. Нужно, чтобы количество слайдеров в слайдере помещалось на всю видимую ширину, независимо от ширины экрана, а ширина самих слайдов оставалась неизменной, а также расстояние между ними. Я прописа свойство slidesPerView: 'auto', но на экран выводится только один слайд. Как сделать так, чтобы выводились слайды друг за другом, и те, что не вмещаются в блок слайдера, скрывались по сторонам. Вот мой код:

```
const Slider: React.FC = () => {
    const sliderSettings: SwiperOptions = {
        modules: [Navigation],
        spaceBetween: 30,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        direction: 'horizontal',
        grabCursor: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    };

    return (
        <SliderContainer>
            <PrevButton className="swiper-button-prev">
                &#8249;
            </PrevButton>
            <SliderContent>
                <Swiper {...sliderSettings}>
                    <SwiperSlide>
                        <Card title='title' description='description' />
                    </SwiperSlide>
                    <SwiperSlide>
                        <Card title='title' description='description' />
                    </SwiperSlide>
                    <SwiperSlide>
                        <Card title='title' description='description' />
                    </SwiperSlide>
                    <SwiperSlide>
                        <Card title='title' description='description' />
                    </SwiperSlide>
                    <SwiperSlide>
                        <Card title='title' description='description' />
                    </SwiperSlide>
                    <SwiperSlide>
                        <Card title='title' description='description' />
                    </SwiperSlide>
                </Swiper>
            </SliderContent>
            <NextButton className="swiper-button-next">
                &#8250;
            </NextButton>
        </SliderContainer>
    );
}

export default Slider;
```

Comment: ваш слайдер скорее всего [блочный элемент](https://learn.javascript.ru/display), занимая всю ширину. можно попробовать его сделать inline-block, либо для тонкой настройки размещения элементов использовать [flexbox](https://metanit.com/web/html5/12.1.php)